# How to traverse through a DOM object with C#?

Tags: c#, dom, automated-tests, ranorex

I have a Web page where I have to traverse the DOM to find out all elements that have a `class` that starts with `"accordion-toggle "`. Each such object gets a similar class assigned, when the accordion widget is opened/closed:
[image]

To make an automated black-box test for Ranorex, where all accordions are clicked & their behaviour checked, I need a DOM-like object that contains all accordions in a page so that the automated testware can click through the objects & check whether they behave properly. How can I extract this information? I try for two days now to see the rather very hierarchical structure of the page and wonder, if there is an easy way to extract this information.

**Edit:**

Actually, there is a way to do it, but I get a `System.OutOfMemoryException`, although there is plenty of memory available on the server. Here you go:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Finds the accordion widgets
    /// </summary>
    public void FindAccordionWidgets()
    {
        Report.Log(ReportLevel.Info, "Code", "FindAccordionWidgets() started…");
        IList<Ranorex.Unknown> elementList = repo.Home.Self.Find<Ranorex.Unknown>("//*[@class~'accordion-toggle'][@visible='true']");
        Report.Log(ReportLevel.Info, "Code", "elementList populated.");

        foreach (Ranorex.Unknown elementItem in elementList)
        {
            // Do whatever you want here
            Report.Log(ReportLevel.Info, "Code", "elementItem " + elementItem.FlavorName + isOfType + elementItem.GetType());
        }
    }
```

Comment: this may helpful https://www.ranorex.com/forum/dynamic-coding-using-c-find-children-t7555.html

Comment: Where do you get the out of memory exception?

Comment: If you use the Ranorex Spy to find all items matching the XPath on the Find<Ranorex.Unknown> line of code, how many elements do you get? All you can do in code, you can test in the Spy first...

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Sorry, but I left that company and do not use Ranorex for the time being.